Как сделать .exe чтобы он работал
Как сделать так чтобы .exe работал на другом пк

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Используйте PyInstaller для создания .exe файла из вашего Python-скрипта. Для этого выполните следующие шаги:
Установите PyInstaller:
pip install pyinstaller

Скомпилируйте ваш скрипт в .exe:
pyinstaller --onefile your_script.py

Это создаст .exe файл в папке dist. После создания .exe файла - скопируйте его на другой компьютер и запустите.

Здесь именно вопрос в том как из 1 компьютера перенести на другой. С компа который будет давать файл винда 7, а то который получит 11

Можно скопировать .exe файл на флешку или загрузить их на Google Drive. Это одни из самых простых способов.

Окей проверю и отвечу будет ли работать

Кстати а если вместо того чтобы сделать с pyinstaller так как ты сказал немного по-другому вот так ’pyinstaller -F -w my_script.py’

По этому поводу сказать не могу, так как работал только с PyInstaller. С чем именно ты работал?

Я тоже с pyinstaller работал только немного по другому. В моем комменте выше написал как

Работать будет, но с 100% уверенностью сказать не могу. Возможно, потребуется скопировать папку _internal. Попробуйте сделать и с папкой, и без нее, и сообщите о результате. Если результат будет неутешительным, будем разбираться с проблемой.

Вот только есть одна проблема у меня некогда не садовалась папка _internal всегда только 2 папки и 2 файла (1 из них это код)

Значит работает и без папки.

У себя я запускал таким образом но уже на другом компьютере не работает (я отсылал через тг архивом)

Вы упомянули два файла. Какой из них второй?

2 my_script.space

Вы отправляли, только 1 файл?

Первый я написал в позапрошлом посте script.py и script.space

В архиве отправлял оба

Вы уверены что формат файла .space, в не .spec?

А да . spec Сории просто забыл

Ничего страшного. .spec - файл который создаётся "на потом". Попробуйте в терминале написать "pyinstaller your_script.spec".

Окей потом отвечу

слушай можно поточнее что надо сделать пожалуйста

Есть еще : auto-py-to-exe . у нее графическая оболочка, немного попроще.
Только проблема в следующем с python + windows : из за специфики упакование EXE будут определятся как вирусные и удаляться. Плюс нет ключа на файле.
Если винда удаляет - запаковываем в архив с паролем.
Без ключа дает ставить.
